# How to change language in Rasa NLU when SpaCy supports just tokenization (pl - polish)?

Tags: python, json, nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

How to use Polish language in Rasa NLU project? SpaCy supports Polish in tokenization https://spacy.io/usage/models#alpha-support

My config.json file looks like this:

```
{
"pipeline" : [ "nlp_spacy",
               "tokenizer_spacy",
                "ner_crf",
                "ner_spacy",
                "intent_featurizer_spacy",
                "intent_classifier_sklearn"],
"language" : "en",
"path" : "./models/nlu",
"data" : "./data/training_data.json" 
}
```

but once I change the language for 'pl' the 'language not supported' error occurs.

Should I download different models than these two:

python -m spacy download en_core_web_md

python -m spacy link en_core_web_md en

?

I know I can use it this way:

```
from spacy.lang.pl import Polish
nlp = Polish ()
```

but I don't know how to implement it to my config file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

Now I am trying config.yml:

```
language: "pl"

pipeline:
- name: "tokenizer_whitespace"
- name: "ner_crf"
- name: "intent_featurizer_count_vectors"
- name: "intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding"
  intent_tokenization_flag: false
```

with Rasa NLU bleeding edge version (github + setup.py) . You do not need to download anything else.

Will let you know which version works better:)